# Formula with SUMIFS for selecting multiple variables in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Attached below I show an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Basically I want to have a result based on the chosen item from the dropdown list and dates. If you select Test 1 and dates from 3 Jan to 8 Jan it should show me as result $3, but if I choose Test 2, it should give me $5 as a result.

How can I achieve this?

This is the formula I'm currently using in L16, but it only works for 1 item.

```
=SUMIFS(I3:I12,H3:H12,">="&J16,H3:H12,"<="&K16)
```

[image]

Comment: Web applications, like Google spreadsheet, are off-topic.  Much of the implementation is similar to Excel, so to the extent that's true, an Excel solution will work.  If you are using Google, though, the safe bet in general is to ask the question on the web apps site, where the answer can always be expected to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the Screen Shot:**
[image]
Write this Formula:

```
=IF(F387="Test1",SUMIFS(B390:B399,A390:A399,">="&C402,A390:A399,"<="&D402),IF(F387="Test2",SUMIFS(C390:C399,A390:A399,">="&C402,A390:A399,"<="&D402),IF(F387="Test3",SUMIFS(D390:D399,A390:A399,">="&C402,A390:A399,"<="&D402),IF(F387="Test4",SUMIFS(E390:E399,A390:A399,">="&C402,A390:A399,"<="&D402),0))))
```

**N.B.**
 1. *Please adjust the Data Range as your need, since I've worked in different Data Range.*

2. *This Solution will work with Excel as well as Google Sheet also.*

Comment: Thanks Rahesh! It worked. I'm now trying to add a 2nd dropdown list, with list of names ("Name","Name2","Name3", etc.). If you choose "Name2" and "Test3" it should shift to the next columns, like N1 for "Name2" and O2 for "Test3". In the formula you gave, I added a IF(AND(.....)). It works but I would use a lot of code when having more names. Like copy paste, but I don't want that. Maybe is there a simple form?

Comment: Happy to help You, Keep asking,, if you have any Query related to this one please post a NEW QUESTION, i'll try to solve it also. :-)

Comment: New question: https://superuser.com/questions/1324143/display-value-based-from-multiple-dropdown-list-with-if-and-sumifs