# Display value based from multiple dropdown list with IF, AND, SUMIFS

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, dropdownlist

Attached below I show an example of what I'm trying to achieve

Basically I want to have a result based on the chosen item from 2 dropdown list and a range of date. If you select "Name1" "Test 1" and dates from 2 Jan to 8 Jan it should show me as result $3, but if I choose "Name2" "Test2", it should give me $9 as a result.

I'm using this formula and it works fine, with IF, AND, SUMIFS. The problem is when adding 30 names, writing down code for each one is a mess. Is there a simple way?

```
=IF(AND(I16="Test 1",H16="Name"),SUMIFS(I3:I12,H3:H12,">="&J16,H3:H12,"<="&K16),
   IF(AND(I16="Test 2",H16="Name"),SUMIFS(J3:J12,H3:H12,">="&J16,H3:H12,"<="&K16),
   IF(AND(I16="Test 1",H16="Name2"),SUMIFS(L3:L12,H3:H12,">="&J16,H3:H12,"<="&K16),
   IF(AND(I16="Test 2",H16="Name2"),SUMIFS(M3:M12,H3:H12,">="&J16,H3:H12,"<="&K16)))))
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Even if you use VBA (macro) then in this case also, all 30 names must be tested, one method is CASE ,, ENDCASE. Therefore you need to show us a proper combination of NAMEs & TESTs with Columns, then only I can suggest any method to to fix it.